# type conversion failure

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks something like this:

[image]

The empty fields can be null or an empty string, I'm not sure.
I want to update the **firstName** field to be all the characters in the **name** field until the **-**, whether **firstname** was empty or not. It doesn't matter what was in there before the update.

I tried the following queries without success:

```
update table1
set firstname= Left([Name],InStr(1,[Name],"-")-1)
```

But I got a conversion error on two records.

I tried this:

```
update table1
set firstname= iif(name is null,firstname,Left([Name],InStr(1,[Name],"-")-1))
```

But I still got an error.

Why is this happening and how to I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is that you cannot use a string function on a null value. First you need to turn the Nulls into blanks, and then extract the name. 
`IIf(IsNull([Name]),"",Left([Name],InStr(1,[Name],"-")-1))`

This should prevent the type conversion

Answer (score 0):

what is the webaddress field?

from the table you have above it seems to me you want to:

update table1
set name = iif(name is null,null,Left([Name],InStr(1,[Name],"-")-1))

Comment: Oh, gosh, sorry. I pasted the real query instead of the one that suites my example. Fixed it.